# Random vector a with elements from the uniform distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R and I'm looking through a book called "Discovering Statistics using R".

Although the book implies you don't need any statistical background, some of the content isn't covered/explained...

I'm wondering how you simulate a random vector a with 200 elements from the uniform distribution on the interval (-50, 50).

Maybe I'm unsure because of the terminology used. For the example I just created a vector with 200 elements that range inbetween -50 and 50... I'm just checking if this is correct.

Or is there a function that generates random values like there is in Java? I haven't found anything on google either regarding R providing random values.

Comment: Yes, like I said. But I was unsure of the "Uniform Distribution" terminology. Once the answer below confirmed the function and that my assumption was correct, I was able to read about it in greater detail knowing I was looking at the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
runif(200, -50, 50)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Oh, neat! Thanks for the swift answer! Perfect! Great function.

Comment: `sample(-50:50, 200, rep=TRUE)` would provide the same functionality.

Comment: @Dinre This will only sample integers and hence is not equivalent to `runif`.

Comment: This is true.  I was assuming the need was for integer sampling, which the OP did NOT state.  Good call.

Comment: I assumed stating `Uniform Distributions` suggests real numbers, not integer or whole numbers. But both are nice to know anyway.